# Unable to import icons from @mui/icons-material

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

This error popping while running code.

```
wait  - compiling...
error - ../../../../../node_modules/@mui/icons-material/esm/utils/createSvgIcon.js:1:0
Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/material/utils'
null
```

Edit : Already have installed @mui/material package.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Definitely!, I will follow from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@mui/icons-material` has `@mui/material` as a [peer dependency](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/df4f0818ab29df4472c3ef312c89d6225f5f1049/packages/mui-icons-material/package.json#L44). It means if you [install](https://mui.com/components/icons/#installation) the icon package, you also have to install `@mui/material`:

```
npm install @mui/material
```

Comment: Yes, already have installed @mui/material but the problem still persisting.

Comment: @MallikarjunMG delete your `package-lock.json` and try installing both packages again.

Comment: It worked. May the Force be with you!.